# Clicking Inside the text inside div and table

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click inside a text boxthat is inside a div which itself is inside a table. I have tried numerous approaches but none seems to work

This is the code for the element:

```
<tr valign="top"><td id="xNEPk-chdex" style="height:100%"><div id="xNEPk" class="labelRowCnt z-div"><span id="xNEPm" class="z-label">Username:</span></div></td><td id="xNEPk-chdex2" class="z-hbox-separator"><img style="height:0;width:0"></td><td id="xNEPl-chdex" style="height:100%"><div id="xNEPl" class="compRowCnt z-div"><input id="xNEPn" class="login z-textbox" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text" name="j_username"></div></td></tr>
```

I cannot go with the element ID as the element ID keeps changing every time I refresh the page

I have tried the following method some of which are

```
element =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class=".compRowCnt.z-div"]/input[@class=".login.z-textbox"]')))
element.click()

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login.z-textbox")
element.click()

element =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"j_username")))
element.click()
```

But none seems to work. Every time I get element not found.

I want to be able to click inside the textbox so that I can provide my username using send keys.

Can anyone please help me? I am using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. As the desired element is a dynamic element so to `click()` the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.login.z-textbox[name='j_username']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='login z-textbox' and @name='j_username']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, this works like a charm. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Great answer! @Mohamedrafiq see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote